# Reactjs form onSubmit not working

Tags: forms, button, submit, reactjs

I am trying to build a dynamic div that contains different components based on the state. I have my custom components Active, Stable and Form.

```
render: function () {
  var components = [];
  if (this.state.isActive) {
     components.push(React.DOM.Active));
  } 
  if (this.state.isStable) {
     components.push(React.DOM.Stable({}));
  }
  if (this.state.visible) {
    components.push(React.DOM.Form({}));
  }
  return React.DOM.div({}, components);
}
```

The Form component is a simple form that has

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Submitted');
}
render: function() {
  return React.DOM.form({onSubmit: this.handleSubmit}, [React.DOM.button({},'Submit')]);
```

}

The handleSubmit method is never invoked. But if I change the code to:

```
render: function () {
  var components = [];
  components.push(React.DOM.Form({}));
  return React.DOM.div({}, components);
}
```

Does anyone know where the problem could come from?

Comment: What happens when you change the code? You don't specify.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to specify it! It's written 'Submitted' in the console and the default behaviour of the event is prevented.

Answer (score 1):

The handleSubmit method is not written correctly. it should be

```
handleSubmit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Submitted');
},
//(dont forget the comma to separate methods  :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `{onSubmit: this.handleSubmit}` in your `React.DOM.form` call.

Comment: I have written it but I forgot to paste it.